# Why is a question force edited to meet the answer given below but not the question which was asked previously?

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

After going through this [question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-to-deal-with-serial-editing) I am asking a different question  as this deals only with serial editing.
I have a [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/do-some-aircraft-lower-the-landing-gear-mid-flight) which I had recently updated with an image to prove that the below given answer is not at all true to the point. But again the question is  force edited back to meet the answers given below but not the question which I had asked.

Let me explain in Example.

I had asked a question regarding A and got an answer regarding B(this answer B is invalid to A), instead of giving answer for A the question is force edited to meet the answer B  .So why is the question forcefully edited to meet the answer B

Answer (score 4):

This question itself is an interesting case, because there's a lot of incomplete data and assumptions inherent in the question (among them that the aircraft are "mid-flight" and not enroute to a nearby airport).

I've partially-reverted the question with a synthesis of what appear to be the *most relevant* edits (where you saw the aircraft, and a map showing your position relative to the nearest airport) which seems to be the most correct subset of edits to include.

Based on the question history I think these changes adequately capture your intent in asking the question, and appropriately align with the best answers given (one explaining why what you're probably seeing is planes on approach to Begumpet Airport – VOHY; the other addressing abnormal procedures like handling a brake temperature warning).

---

I've thrown a 24-hour lock on the question mostly so it doesn't keep accumulating edits while we try to get it right - if you think I've missed the mark with my changes leave a comment here or [pop by chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) and we can work on nailing it down to a version that satisfies everyone.

Comment: seeing this now. you might want to include this information: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16931563#16931563

Answer (score 2):

As for the reason that prompted the edit, you are again making assuptions.

First thing first. **This is not serial editing**: serial editing refers to the practice of a single user to edit several question with small or minor corrections. This was a major edit.

**The question has not been forced to meet the answer**: the question as originally posted was unsuitable for the site and would have been [closed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). **The edit has been made to avoid deletion**. You provided the information that prompted the edit (in the comments that have been deleted by a moderator).

**Edits to salvage a question/answer are encouraged in the SE network:** if the edit is not likely, there is even a specific flag:

> **Very Low Quality**
>
> This question/answer has severe formatting or content problems. This question/answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.